# Tagging a Similar category with repeated sequence of numbers in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sequence, sequence-generators

#### Below is the reproducible code

```
colo = ['red', 'red', 'red','cross','cross','red', 'red', 'red','cross','cross','cross',
            'cross','cross', 'red', 'red','cross', 'red','cross','cross']
    dt = pd.DataFrame()
    dt['seq']=[i for i in range(len(colo))]
    dt['col'] =  colo
```

#### Expected Output:

[image]

The column `seq` and `col` is been given & `Expected_col` is required to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `eq` + `diff` + `ne` + `cumsum` to greate groups; then use boolean indexing to fill in values:

```
cond = dt['col'].eq('red')
s = dt.loc[cond, 'seq'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()
dt['Expected_col'] = dt['col']
dt.loc[cond, 'Expected_col'] = 'RED' + (s.max() + 1 - s).astype(str)
```

Output:

```
    seq    col Expected_col
0     0    red         RED4
1     1    red         RED4
2     2    red         RED4
3     3  cross        cross
4     4  cross        cross
5     5    red         RED3
6     6    red         RED3
7     7    red         RED3
8     8  cross        cross
9     9  cross        cross
10   10  cross        cross
11   11  cross        cross
12   12  cross        cross
13   13    red         RED2
14   14    red         RED2
15   15  cross        cross
16   16    red         RED1
17   17  cross        cross
18   18  cross        cross
```